# Multiplication modulo proving a set is a group conform conditions

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given is the following explanation.

A group is a set, together with a binary operation $\odot$, such that the following conditions hold:

- For all a, b $\in$ S it holds that a $\odot$ b $\in$ S

Now, i have to show that the Set = {1, 2 ... 16, 17} together with multiplication modulo 18 is not a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication modulo $14$ means the value of $a\cdot b \pmod {14}$. So for $a = 1, b = 2$, $a\odot b = 1 \cdot 2 \pmod {14} = 2.$ This is an associative operation on the integers, because multiplication is associative.

HINT for the first: The identity element here is $1$. Show that $2$ has no multiplicative inverse $a'$ (no element in the group such that  $2\cdot a' = a'\cdot 2 = 1$. Indeed, you can simply show that your set is not closed under the binary operation $\odot$: Calculate for example, $2 \odot 7 =  2\cdot 7 \pmod{14}$.

---

HINT for the second: Note that $13$ is prime, and any group $\mathbb Z^*_{p}$ where p is prime has $p - 1$ elements, and is equal to $\{1, 2, \cdots, p-1\}$.

$1$ again is your identity element: this is easy enough to confirm. You can also verify that the inverse $a'$ of every element $a\in \mathbb Z^*{13} \in \mathbb Z^*_{13}$. You can also confirm that for any two elements $a, b \in \mathbb Z^*_{13}$, $a \odot b = a\cdot b \pmod {13} \in \mathbb Z^*_{13}.$

Comment: It might sound a bit dumb, but I dont get the multiplicative inverse a' part. For the first one it would be correct to say 2 $\odot$ 7, or am I wrong? And for the second one, how do I prove that it fits all the conditions. Simply stating it is not enough I guess..

Comment: For the first, $2\odot 7 = 2 \cdot 7 = 14 = 0\pmod{14}$. But $0 \notin \mathbb Z^*_{14}$. So it's not even closed under the binary operation. Hence, it is not a group. The second set *is* indeed a group. Every element in $\mathbb Z^*_{13}$ is relatively prime to $13$, and hence, 1 is the identity, every element has an inverse, and the set is closed under multiplication modulo 13. You can test that in both cases, $\odot$ is associative.

Comment: Hint: Given $a\in \mathbb Z_{13}^*$, apply the Euclidean algorithm to $a$ and $13$ to find $a'\in \mathbb Z_{13}^*$.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU to go with green! =1

Answer (score 0):

Hint for your first question: compute $2\odot7$.

Comment: Ofcourse, how stupid of me, thanks for your reply! But how do I prove that the second one is a group then? Saying that it fits all the conditions wouldn't be enough I guess.

Comment: @user108287 You're certainly welcome.  And certainly you don't know how many times I felt as “stupid” as you claim to be now.  It's in fact no matter of “stupidness” but of enlightenment instead.  -- That's what's all about.  Keep on stunning.